# First,real programming project:Create a Database from a web dictionary

Tags: python, database, dictionary

I want to create a programme that will take a word list, search on a web dictionary (like webster learning dictionary,cambridge learner's,..) and will create a text file in this shape:

> ```
> word1 pronunciation definition example sentence ... ...
> word2 pronunciation definition example sentence ... ...
> ....
> ```

and I have a few questions:

is it possible to do this?
if it is what tools should I use?
If It is possible with python,what lib. should I use?
(I prefer python cause it is language I am learning)

I just need a general idea of the way to take.

I'm still a big noob with programming but, I think that If I work on some personal project,
I'll make good progress.

P.S.: My english is far from perfect,sorry about it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would not be that difficult, the main thing would be figuring out how to query the website.
These would be the basic steps:

- map query string to url:

  - You need to figure out how the website works (Examine the source ot the html to figure paramters of the forms.) Some websites have public API's that make it easier.
- get web page: `urllib2`
- parse page for your answer: `BeautifulSoup`. Separate your info from the rest of web page.
- write info to a file

Comment: How can I know if a website has a public api?

Answer (score -1):

This is possible, but in order to maintain scalability you will need the rigth algorithm:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aho%E2%80%93Corasick_string_matching_algorithm

In python this is: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ahocorasick/0.9

Just capture the event where the search tree reaches a state in which a search word is discovered and act upon it. The aforementioned wiki page points you to some useful resources.

Greetz,
J.